# Permission probllem gaining access to a temp folder

Tags: php, google-app-engine, silverstripe

I am trying to get SilverStripe to work on Google-App-Engine but it give this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'Permission problem gaining access to a temp folder. Please create a folder named silverstripe-cache in the base folder of the installation and ensure it has the correct permissions' in /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/framework/core/TempPath.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/framework/core/TempPath.php(9): getTempParentFolder('/base/data/home...')
#1 /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/framework/core/Constants.php(238): getTempFolder('/base/data/home...')
#2 /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/framework/main.php(58): require_once('/base/data/home...')
#3 /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/index.php(66): require_once('/base/data/home...')
#4 {main}
thrown in /base/data/home/apps/s~my_app_id/1.371770119107113254/framework/core/TempPath.php on line 84
```

Comment: So what is in /framework/core/TempPath.php on line 84? Have you tried anything to resolve the issue?

Comment: Have you created a `silverstripe-cache` folder in the root directory with write privileges?

Comment: Do you mean the root folder of the app? And how do I give it write privileges?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to configure the temp folder to point to Google Cloud Storage using gs:// stream wrapper. The local file-system is not writable on GAE which is why the default will not work.

From comment by LevB it seems you set TEMP_FOLDER constant to the appropriate location. In this case it should be something like `gs://mybucket/temp`.

Be sure to create a bucket and setup the permissions to allow you app to access it. For more information see: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/php/googlestorage/.

Comment: where do I change the `TEMP_FOLDER`?

Comment: From LevB's comment: http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/environment-management.

Answer (score 0):

Create writable directory and set it as cache directory with TEMP_FOLDER constant.

Read [Environment management](http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/environment-management) for more information.